# Program crashes when input to double pointer array which is in struct point

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

The program I am instructed to write is to gather student information. It is very basic, but in the instructions, I don't the number of students (not a problem) or the number of tests per student (problem). I am instructed to create a pointer to a struct and create a double pointer array to each student. I did that.

But, every time I try to enter test scores for the students, my program crashes. I've tried studentData->testscores in my enterData() function, I've tried studentData[i].testScores[j], *studentData->testScores, and nothing seems to work.

Could someone please point my in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct StudentInfo
{
    string name;
    string idNum;
    double* testScores;
    double average;
    char grade;
};

StudentInfo enterData(StudentInfo*, int, int);//Add data to the student
//void displayData(StudentInfo*, int);//Display the student info and grade

int main()
{
int numStudents;
int numTests;

cout << "Enter the amount of students to input: ";
cin >> numStudents;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Enter the number of test scores per students: ";
cin >> numTests;
cin.ignore();

StudentInfo* studentData = new StudentInfo[numStudents];

for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++);
{
    studentData->testScores = new double[numTests];
    studentData++;
}


//Let the user enter students information
enterData(studentData, numStudents, numTests);

return 0;
}
//*************************
//define enterData function
//*************************
StudentInfo enterData(StudentInfo* studentData, int numStudents, int numTests)
{
int testTotal = 0; //Keep a total of the tests.
double testScore; //Variable to hold user input of test score.
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter data for Student #" << i + 1;
    cout << "\n-------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nName: ";
    getline(cin, studentData[i].name);
    while(studentData[i].name.empty())
    {
        cout << "Oops! You didn't enter the students's name!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter customer's name: ";
        getline (cin, studentData[i].name);
    }
    //Get Student's Id Number
    cout << "ID Number: ";
    getline(cin, studentData[i].idNum);
    while(studentData[i].idNum.empty())
    {
        cout << "Oops! You didn't enter the students's ID Number!" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter student's ID Number: ";
        getline (cin, studentData[i].idNum);
    }
        //Get Student's Test Scores
        cout << "Enter Test Scores for Student #" << i + 1 << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < numTests; j++)
        {
            cout << "Test #" << j + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> testScore;
            cin.ignore();
            studentData[i].testScores[j] = testScore;
            testTotal += testScore;
        }
    //Save Students Average
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Student's Average: " << testTotal/numTests;

    studentData[i].average = testTotal/numTests;

    //Save Students Grade
    if(studentData[i].average > 90)
        studentData[i].grade = 'A';
    else if(studentData[i].average > 80)
        studentData[i].grade = 'B';
    else if(studentData[i].average > 70)
        studentData[i].grade = 'C';
    else if(studentData[i].average > 60)
        studentData[i].grade = 'D';
    else
            studentData[i].grade = 'F';
        cout << "Student's Grade: " << studentData[i].grade << endl;

    }
    return *studentData;
}
```

Comment: clean up the code: remove the parts which aren't relevant to your question, and test that it reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing ***undefined behavior*** because you're trying to access memory out of the array's bounds:

```
// you create an array and keep pointer to first element:
StudentInfo* studentData = new StudentInfo[numStudents];

// try to increment this pointer till it points behind this array:
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++);                        // <-- semicolon !!!
{
    studentData->testScores = new double[numTests];
    studentData++;
}

// and use this pointer that points to incorrect memory:
enterData(studentData, numStudents, numTests);
```

Additionally, there is a semicolon after your `for` which causes the "body" of your loop (which because of semicolon is nothing but annonymous nested scope) to be executed only once, which is enough for function `enterData` to iterate over students starting from 2nd element, invoking UB at the end.

---

What you should do is:

```
StudentInfo* studentData = new StudentInfo[numStudents];

for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    studentData[i].testScores = new double[numTests];
}

enterData(studentData, numStudents, numTests);
```

... and just to remind you, note that cleaning of this should reflect the way it was allocated:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    delete[] studentData[i].testScores;
}
delete[] studentData;
```

Comment: Not to mention the stray semicolon after the `for` so the loop doesnt even get executed...

Comment: I really appreciate it. I was trying to use the pointer notation with the "studentData->testScores". And the deal with the semicolon after the for loop really didn't help matters any. :) The semicolon of death. Thanks, it works now!